# Upper Bound on Expectation of a Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ be i.i.d random variables. Suppose $(\mathbb{E}|X_i|^p)^{1/p}=M < \infty, 1 < p < 2$. Let $X_i=X_i\mathbf{1}_{|X_i| \leq c}, Y_i = X_i\mathbf{1}_{|X_i| > c}, \mu=\mathbb{E}X_i$.

I'm trying to bound bound $\mathbb{P}(|\frac{SN}{n}| > \delta)$ and then use Chernoff's method.

I think we know that $\mathbb{E}|\sum(X_i+Y_i)=\sqrt{n}[\mathbb{E}(X_1-\mathbb{E}[X_i])^2]^{1/2}+2n\mathbb{E}|Y_1|$.

We know that$(|\sum_i (X_i+Y_i| \geq n\delta) \leq \sigma^2/n\delta^2$.

Comment: You're going to have to give us a bit more context. Are there any restrictions on $X_1$ and $Y_1?$

Comment: thanks edited the op

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|Y_i| \geq c$ almost surely under the condition that $\{|X_i| \ge c\}$, implying that $|Y_i/c| \geq 1$ under the condition that $\{|X_i| \ge c\}$. Thus, we have,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{|Y_i|}{c}, |X_i| \ge c \right] & \leq \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{|Y_i|^p}{c^p}, |X_i| \ge c  \right] \\
& \leq c^{-p} \mathbb{E}[|X_i|^p \mathbb{1}_{|X_i| \geq c}] \\
& \leq c^{-p} \mathbb{E}[|X_i|^p] \leq c^{-p}M^p.
\end{align*}
By noting that $Y_i = 0$ if $|X_i| < c$, we obtain, $\mathbb{E}[|Y_i|] \leq c^{1-p}M^p$.

For the second part, we have,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[(X - \mu)^2] & \leq \mathbb{E}[2X^2 + 2\mu^2] \\
& \leq 2\mathbb{E}[X^2] + 2\mu^2 \\
& \leq 2\mathbb{E}[X^2] + 2\mathbb{E}[X^2] \\
& \leq 4\mathbb{E}[X^2] \leq 4c^{2-p}M^p,
\end{align*}
where the last step uses the given bound.

Comment: thanks so much!! i tried to use this to create an upper bound but im not sure how (see op)